# Intellij is not opening a project from other locations

Tags: intellij

I recently switched from window to ubuntu and now i want to open my project in intellij but there is no drive showing only.Please help

Comment: In order to help you, you will need to specify additional details like, what is "no drive" mean?

Comment: Like in Window Drive E,F etc .But here they are other locations

Comment: Linux does not work like windows, there's no C drive nor D Drive ... use `sudo fdisk -l` to check your drives then you can mount them in `/c/` or `/d/` for example

Comment: project i have is in /dev/sda2

Comment: What should i do to open the project from that

Comment: you can't, you need to mount it either manually of fstab -- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/mount.8.html